# Automatic testing for Microsoft Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, testing, botframework

I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework to create a bot in NodeJs.

I manually tested the bot with the Bot Emulator, but I'm looking for the best method to automate testing for the bot.

Does Microsoft provide any tool for automatically running test or are there any other methods which can support the bot to be test automatically?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy link if you're looking for Node: https://github.com/microsoftly/BotTester

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much useful this will be for you, but if you can use MS Test framework, have a look at [this](https://azure.github.io/learnAnalytics-AdvancedFeaturesforMicrosoftBotFramework/lab02-testing_bots/docs/2_Unit_Testing_Bots.html) URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at https://github.com/jvanderbiest/directline-jabber

> DirectLine-Jabber focusses on automated integration testing for the
>   Microsoft BotFramework. Using your BotFramework emulator transcript
>   files it will check if your bot responds as it is supposed to respond.

You can use the emulator to create a chat conversation, then save the transcript, deploy your bot and replay it to your deployed bot instance.